# Network section not showing in flipper debugger app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flipper

I have installed Flipper for debugging my react-native app but not able to see network section.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

To add functionality like this you need to add the plugin on the native side. This requires changes to both the Android and iOS side of things to get it hooked in. This is a link to their docs on adding this: https://fbflipper.com/docs/setup/network-plugin